# Setting/removing parent styles on component load/unload

Tags: angular

Looking for the proper way to set styles on all parent elements of a component when it is routed to, and remove such styles after the component is routed away from.

Trying to recreate a seemingly simple component that exhibits the full-page image behavior demonstrated in [this w3schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryhow_css_fullpage_demo.htm).

The component would have to access all parents up the DOM up to the `html` node to set their heights to 100%. In the case below it would be the `body` and `html` elements.

app.component.html

```
<div class="bgimg-1">
  <div class="caption">
    <span class="border">FULL PAGE</span><br>
    <span class="border">BACKGROUND IMAGE</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.component.css

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font: 400 15px/1.8 "Lato", sans-serif;
    color: #777;
}

.caption {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
}

.caption span.border {
    background-color: #111;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 18px;
    font-size: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
}

.bgimg-1 {
    background-image: url(img_parallax.jpg);
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0.65;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {}
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title></title>
      <base href="/">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    </head>
    <body>
      <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess on the Oninit lifecycle hook of your component you can use jquery or js to change your styles.

Comment: @Ramesh introducing jquery to angular isn't a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, this is generally not a very angular approach to the world. the child shouldn't be dictating the parent's layout, and you definitely shouldn't be messing with the html or body tags. The CORRECT way to do this IMO is to have both a `StandardLayoutComponent` and a `FullScreenLayoutComponent` and setting up your routing to use them correctly, and in your global css, just commit to full 100% height html and body tags:

```
[
  {
    path: '',
    component: StandardLayoutComponent,
    children: [... all standard layout children ...]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: FullScreenLayoutComponent,
    children: [... all full screen layout children ...]
  }
]
```

and your app component template is just a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and nothing else.

an alternative is to use a directive and service that can alter the styles / classes of the elements it's attached to:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class FullScreenService {
  private fullScreenSource = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);
  fullScreen$ = this.fullScreenSource.pipe(distinctUntilChanged());
  setFullScreen(fullScreen: boolean) {
    this.fullScreenSource.next(fullScreen);
  }
}

@Directive({
  selector: [fullScreen]
})
export class FullScreenDirective implements OnDestroy {
  // set your css for the full-screen class globally
  @HostBinding('class.full-screen') isFullScreen = false;
  private sub: Subscription
  constructor(private fullScreenService: FullScreenService) {
    this.sub = this.fullScreenService.fullScreen$.subscribe(v => this.isFullScreen = v);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe()
  }
}
```

attach said directive to all concerned elements:

```
<div fullScreen> ... </div>
```

then inject service into controlling component and use it:

```
@Component({...})
export class ControllingComponent implements OnDestroy {
  constructor(private fullScreenService: FullScreenService) {
    this.fullScreenService.setFullScreen(true);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.fullScreenService.setFullScreen(false);
  }
}
```

this would get it done, but i don't recommend as it's children dictating the parent's layout, which generally isn't sound architecture.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! Been looking for a PROPER solution for 3 days. The first solution had crossed my mind, it just seemed very extreme to be the correct one. If I may ask something somehow related: There are semantic rules to HTML/5 elements about ordering of elements, and which elements should go within others, etc. Does it mess up browser semantics to have all of these angular elements between HTML/5 elements on the page? Would such an Angular page still pass linting/be spec-compliant?

Comment: So upon attempting this, Angular complains about there being "no base href" set. Turns out, Angular pretty much requires your `head` tag to be present in the index.html document, which would mean your `html` tag would need to be there as well. They can't be within a component as they are needed for routing. So the first solution you presented will not work. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: I thought about putting `<body>` in the FullScreenLayout component and routing to that under `<head>`, and using `:host` to retrieve the `<html>` element, but turns out if there is no `<body>` element in index.html, Angular will also wrap your `<app-root>` element in a `<body>` element.

Comment: both solutions involve just keeping everything inside the body tag. and using normal css to set the html / body height to 100% all the time

Comment: But if the height is 100% all the time, other layouts on the site don't work. The site only has a full-page image as a landing page. The rest of the site is accessed from a header on the landing page and has scrolling content, and it wouldn't be scrollable with `<html>` at 100% height.

Comment: somehow scrolling seems to be working. Going to mark it as the answer :)